# Class.getConstructor fails to find compatible constructor

Tags: java, reflection

Having problems with a factory class, I pass in a human readable name that maps to a class that has a single constructor with a single argument, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.satgraf.evolution2.observers.VSIDSTemporalLocalityEvolutionObserver.<init>(com.satlib.evolution.ConcreteEvolutionGraph)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2892)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1723)
at com.satlib.evolution.observers.EvolutionObserverFactory.getByName(EvolutionObserverFactory.java:84)
at com.satgraf.evolution2.UI.Evolution2GraphFrame.main(Evolution2GraphFrame.java:229)
```

These are the classes in question, I have about a dozen of these things in different projects, they all work without problem - including one that is almost identical, can't see why this one is failing:

```
public EvolutionObserver getByName(String name, EvolutionGraph graph){
if(classes.get(name) == null){
  return null;
}
else{
  try {
    Constructor<? extends EvolutionObserver> con = classes.get(name).getConstructor(graph.getClass());
    EvolutionObserver i = con.newInstance(graph);
    observers.add(i);
    return i;
  } 
  catch (InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(EvolutionObserverFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    return null;
  }
}
}
```

The class being instantiated is:

```
public class VSIDSTemporalLocalityEvolutionObserver extends JPanel implements EvolutionObserver{
    public VSIDSTemporalLocalityEvolutionObserver(EvolutionGraph graph){
    ...
    }
...
}
```

The argument `graph` is of type:

```
public class ConcreteEvolutionGraph extends ConcreteCommunityGraph implements EvolutionGraph{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getConstructor` requires an exact match on the parameter types; it does not attempt to find a 'compatible' constructor.  The [`getConstructor` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) simply says "The constructor to reflect is the public constructor of the class represented by this Class object whose formal parameter types match those specified by `parameterTypes`."  (In current OpenJDK, `getConstructor` [delegates to](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u40/jdk/file/c7bbaa04eaa8/src/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java#l1825) `getConstructor0` which [loops through all the constructors and compares the given parameter array](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u40/jdk/file/c7bbaa04eaa8/src/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java#l3077) against `constructor.getParameterTypes()`.)

At runtime, your code looks for a constructor taking a parameter of type `ConcreteEvolutionGraph` (`graph.getClass()` returns `graph`'s runtime type), and `VSIDSTemporalLocalityEvolutionObserver` doesn't have one.

If you're really looking for a constructor taking `EvolutionGraph`, pass `EvolutionGraph.class` to `getConstructor` instead.  If instead you want any constructor that could be called with the graph's runtime type, you'll need to manually loop over the result of `getConstructors()` looking for a single-argument constructor for which `graph.getClass().isAssignableTo(ctor.getParameterTypes()[0])`.  Note there may be more than one, and when interfaces are involved, there may not be a most-specific one.  You'll have to decide how to break ties.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. In the end I did just pass in EvolutionGraph, I had been hoping for a more generic option as I have a second function that takes a slightly different argument, but that will have to do.